# How do programmers create a cross platform installer for both Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, installation

I have searched high and low for installers to customize after creating my applications (small, medium, and much bigger) in size.  Yes, portable apps great but most people just want to install and also have it just update when updates are available and install and restart the next time or at least warn the user to save the work before the Application can reopen.

**Yes, I have looked at NSIS and other installers, but they are merely for windows and not for both windows and Linux. Some of these installer projects have been discontinued. Most people who use Linux don't like to always build from the source.**

**I was wondering how I can create a POSIX compliant installer that my software can install on both Windows and Linux.  What are the steps involved? I assume most or all installers use C++ to do all of the grunt work. I am interested in creating my own to fully understand C++ and how it works. This why I really need to know how an installer is made.** **Any helpful advice is welcomed**.
**Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Websites I install from detect the OS from the browser and provide either the Windows, Mac, Linux or OS/2 installer as required.

Comment: I think most projects use different tools for different targets. The NSIS compiler can run on posix but the generated installer is still Windows-only.